# Disable/Enable Control onPaint event , but Changes not reflecting

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to Enable/Disable control in OnPaint event, but Changes are not getting reflected. How ever if toggle with other application changes getting reflected(using ALT+TAB)

```
procedure TfrmBase.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var 
...
...  
begin

  flg := False;
  for i := ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    Temp := Components[i];

    if (Temp is TToolButton) then
    begin

            (Temp as TToolButton).Enabled := SomeFuncWhichReturnBoolean;

    end
    else if (Temp is TButton) then

          (Temp as TButton).Enabled   := SomeFuncWhichReturnBoolean ;


  end;


end;
```

Please suggest

Comment: Ok, so now you added to version tags, for two versions that are 10 years apart. Which one is it?

Comment: Use a `TActionList`, define some actions and wire the actions to the buttons. Each action has an `OnExecute` and `OnUpdate` event

Comment: Don't change state when painting. Really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

OnPaint is for painting, and it's not the right moment to change states. Doing this will at best trigger another paint, or at worst it won't. So either the code doesn't work, or it works inefficiently. Moreover, Paint isn't called all the time. Even when you move the form around there is no guarantee that it will be repainted. So, as a trigger, this is a very unreliable event.

Instead, toggle the control when it it added to or removed from `DisableControlList`. Changing Enabled of the control should trigger a repaint, so you don't have to worry about that part.

You failed to mention what kind of list this is, but maybe it has an OnChange event you can use, or you can wrap it or inherit from it to implement the toggle without making it the responsibility of the procedure that added the control to the list. The code you now have, should be in that OnChange event.

Comment: Thanks, please suggest any event which gets called if any change in GUI like any control state change. TForm doesnt have OnChange

Comment: Application.OnIdle, but please don't use that. You're doing it wrong.

Comment: actually I have to disable all buttons in my Application. I have a base class by which all forms in applications are derived. What i wanted to do - to disable all buttons in a base form method (this method is already getting called in all chaild forms ... mostly contructors). if i will be able to achieve this then i would have to make changes in only one place that is base class. I tried to explain scenario, hope i was able to explain it. Please suggest  , Also please let me know if my approach isnt correct

Comment: @GolezTrol This is a szenario for actions - guess when the actions were updated ;o)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve only doing changes in Base class . not each and every child form , I find it very boring.

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks, yes i will use Actions if nothing quick i can do

Comment: Actions is the way to go. I can't imagine why you thought OnPaint was appropriate. I suggest that you need to revise the basics of Win32.

Comment: Actions are really quick - go for it.  As you progress you will probably find that there is a pattern to the disable/enable logic in all the OnUpdate events that will allow you to code this up very quickly.

Comment: I know actions are also updated OnIdle. If you have a big application and some complexity in enabling/disabling the actions, then it's certainly not quick and can become a serious bottle neck.

Comment: Using Application.OnIdle is fine as long as you know what you are doing. Typically the conditions to be checked are plain boolean values, you can do 100 of those without causing any noticible holdup. And the VCL is usually smart enough not to do anything if a state is set to a value it already had. I find it often better maintainable than using an action lists.

Answer (score 1):

Generally spoken, there is a time to change the states and there is a time to paint the current states. Don't mix them up.

Each button represents an action that will happen when you press the button and this action is maybe allowed or not.

Delphi has a [`TActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnList.TActionList) where you can manage actions. Each action has an `OnExecute` (what should happen) and an `OnUpdate` event. This `OnUpdate` event is a perfect place to enable or disable the action.

```
procedure TFoo.BarActionExecute(Sender:TObject);
begin
  DoBarAction();
end;

procedure TFoo.BarActionUpdate(Sedner:TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TAction).Enabled := CanDoBarAction();
end;
```

Just wire up all the buttons with the actions from your `TActionList`